# What spatial functions are available to shapefiles as "virtual layers" in QGIS DB Manager?

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

Can anyone provide a list of the spatial functions available in the QGIS DB Manager plugin when using shapefiles as Virtual Layers?

I've been trying to use things like ST_DWithin and even ST_Buffer but the queries fail - though ST_Intersects and other functions work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST_Buffer works for me.

The [virtual layer documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html#supported-language) states:

> The underlying engine uses SQLite and Spatialite to operate.
>   It means you can use all of the SQL your local installation of SQLite understands. Functions from SQLite and spatial functions from Spatialite can also be used in a virtual layer query.

[image]

The airports layer in this example is as Shapefile from the QGIS sample data.

Comment: ST_Buffer doesn't work on shapfiles... if you can verify, that would be great... otherwise, yes... can't find a reference either! Is that all part of the plugin itself?

Comment: The airports layer in my screenshot example is a Shapefile. DB Manager is a core plugin. You can also create Virtual layers from the menu Layer | Add Layer

Comment: I don't understand what's going on then... I can't buffer or transform geometry from a shapefile but I can intersect...

Comment: Maybe there is an issue on your platform. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Tried at home on Linux Mint to no avail either... tried different data, can't get it to work...