# Listing all functions available in QGIS's Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, function, virtual-layer

How can I get automatically a list of all functions available for usage in QGIS's Virtual Layer?

From my own understanding/experience and [the QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#supported-query-language), QGIS's Virtual Layer employes a mixture of functions provided in [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html), [SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/), [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html) and the [Functions of QGIS expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#functions-list). (I hope I did not miss anything vital.)

I have seen several topics [What spatial functions are available to shapefiles as “virtual layers” in QGIS DB Manager?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220909/what-spatial-functions-are-available-to-shapefiles-as-virtual-layers-in-qgis-d) and [Virtual layers for QGIS (GitHub)](https://github.com/mhugo/qgis_vlayers), unfortunately, in none of them, I could find the solution to my concern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access directly to the Virtual Layers with the power of Python introspection and well formated QGIS Python modules with this code below executed in the QGIS console:

```py
from db_manager.db_plugins.vlayers import sql_dictionary

print(f"Functions: {sql_dictionary.functions}")
print(f"Math functions: {sql_dictionary.math_functions}")
print(f"String functions: {sql_dictionary.string_functions}")
print(f"Aggregate functions: {sql_dictionary.aggregate_functions}")
print(f"Spatialite functions: {sql_dictionary.spatialite_functions}")
print(f"QGIS functions: {sql_dictionary.qgis_functions}")
```

Results in:

```py
Functions: ['changes', 'coalesce', 'glob', 'ifnull', 'hex', 'last_insert_rowid', 'nullif', 'quote', 'random', 'randomblob', 'replace', 'round', 'soundex', 'total_change', 'typeof', 'zeroblob', 'date', 'datetime', 'julianday', 'strftime']
Math functions: ['Abs', 'ACos', 'ASin', 'ATan', 'Cos', 'Cot', 'Degrees', 'Exp', 'Floor', 'Log', 'Log2', 'Log10', 'Pi', 'Radians', 'Round', 'Sign', 'Sin', 'Sqrt', 'StdDev_Pop', 'StdDev_Samp', 'Tan', 'Var_Pop', 'Var_Samp']
String functions: ['Length', 'Lower', 'Upper', 'Like', 'Trim', 'LTrim', 'RTrim', 'Replace', 'Substr']
Aggregate functions: ['Max', 'Min', 'Avg', 'Count', 'Sum', 'Group_Concat', 'Total', 'Var_Pop', 'Var_Samp', 'StdDev_Pop', 'StdDev_Samp']
Spatialite functions: ['*iszipblob', '*ispdfblob', '*isgifblob', '*ispngblob', '*isjpegblob', '*isexifblob', '*isexifgpsblob', '*geomfromexifgpsblob', 'MakePoint', 'BuildMbr', '*buildcirclembr', 'ST_MinX', 'ST_MinY', 'ST_MaxX', 'ST_MaxY', 'ST_GeomFromText', '*pointfromtext', '*geomfromwkb', '*pointfromwkb', 'ST_AsText', 'ST_AsBinary', '*assvg', '*asfgf', '*geomfromfgf', 'ST_Dimension', 'ST_GeometryType', 'ST_Srid', 'ST_SetSrid', 'ST_isEmpty', 'ST_isSimple', 'ST_isValid', 'ST_Boundary', 'ST_Envelope', 'ST_X', 'ST_Y', 'ST_StartPoint', 'ST_EndPoint', 'ST_Length', 'ST_isClosed', 'ST_isRing', 'ST_Simplify', '*simplifypreservetopology', 'ST_NumPoints', 'ST_PointN', 'ST_Centroid', 'ST_PointOnSurface', 'ST_Area', 'ST_ExteriorRing', 'ST_InteriorRingN', 'ST_NumGeometries', 'ST_GeometryN', 'MbrEqual', 'MbrDisjoint', 'MbrTouches', 'MbrWithin', 'MbrOverlaps', 'MbrIntersects', 'MbrContains', 'ST_Equals', 'ST_Disjoint', 'ST_Touches', 'ST_Within', 'ST_Overlaps', 'ST_Crosses', 'ST_Intersects', 'ST_Contains', 'ST_Relate', 'ST_Distance', 'ST_Intersection', 'ST_Difference', 'ST_Union', 'ST_SymDifference', 'ST_Buffer', 'ST_ConvexHull', 'ST_Transform', '*initspatialmetadata', '*addgeometrycolumn', '*recovergeometrycolumn', '*discardgeometrycolumn', '*createspatialindex', '*creatembrcache', '*disablespatialindex', '*checkspatialmetadata', '*autofdostart', '*autofdostop', '*initfdospatialmetadata', '*addfdogeometrycolumn', '*recoverfdogeometrycolumn', '*discardfdogeometrycolumn', '*filtermbrwithin', '*filtermbrcontains', '*filtermbrintersects', '*buildmbrfilter']
QGIS functions: ['atan2', 'round', 'rand', 'randf', 'clamp', 'scale_linear', 'scale_exp', '_pi', 'to_int', 'toint', 'to_real', 'toreal', 'to_string', 'tostring', 'to_datetime', 'todatetime', 'to_date', 'todate', 'to_time', 'totime', 'to_interval', 'tointerval', 'regexp_match', 'now', '_now', 'age', 'year', 'month', 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'day_of_week', 'title', 'levenshtein', 'longest_common_substring', 'hamming_distance', 'wordwrap', 'regexp_replace', 'regexp_substr', 'concat', 'strpos', '_left', '_right', 'rpad', 'lpad', 'format', 'format_number', 'format_date', 'color_rgb', 'color_rgba', 'ramp_color', 'color_hsl', 'color_hsla', 'color_hsv', 'color_hsva', 'color_cmyk', 'color_cmyka', 'color_part', 'darker', 'lighter', 'set_color_part', 'point_n', 'start_point', 'end_point', 'nodes_to_points', 'segments_to_lines', 'make_point', 'make_point_m', 'make_line', 'make_polygon', 'x_min', 'xmin', 'x_max', 'xmax', 'y_min', 'ymin', 'y_max', 'ymax', 'geom_from_wkt', 'geomFromWKT', 'geom_from_gml', 'relate', 'intersects_bbox', 'bbox', 'translate', 'buffer', 'point_on_surface', 'reverse', 'exterior_ring', 'interior_ring_n', 'geometry_n', 'bounds', 'num_points', 'num_interior_rings', 'num_rings', 'num_geometries', 'bounds_width', 'bounds_height', 'is_closed', 'convex_hull', 'sym_difference', 'combine', '_union', 'geom_to_wkt', 'geomToWKT', 'transform', 'uuid', '_uuid', 'layer_property', 'var', '_specialcol_', 'project_color']
```

Comment: magnifique as usually!

Comment: Or just look at the code https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/db_manager/db_plugins/vlayers/sql_dictionary.py

Comment: Thank you for a hint @RagiYaserBurhum