# Raster pixels to vector points with virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, sql, virtual-layer

I would like to create vector points for each pixel of a raster that is located in polygon, using a Virtual layer.

**Details :**

I have 2 layers:

- P : vectors layer of polygons
- R : raster with value in band 1

I want to create a new vector layers of points in which every pixel of raster is used to generate a point. This operation has to be done only inside (boudaries included) of polygons geometry.
The new vector point should contain fields:

- P : ID of the polygon in which the point is
- R : value of the band 1 of the pixel used to generate the point

**Information:**

This process is not the final aim. In fact, my final aim is to make zonal statistic from pixels raster inside polygon as described there :
[Virtual layer zonal statistic of raster using polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463586/virtual-layer-zonal-statistic-of-raster-using-polygons-in-qgis)
Because I do not find anyway to do this directly I try to devide my process into steps. I imagine this workflow:

1. generate points from pixels in a virtual layer with value band 1
2. make zonal statistic into with virtual layer of the points (vector) into polygons (vector)
   feel free to suggest improvement of this workflow.